# Why does the colour of a thing change when under huge magnification?

Tags: optics, microscopy

For instance, this image:

[image]

shows human eyelashes close up.

The lashes look green, in fact the whole surface area has a strange tint of green Why is this?

Comment: Sounds like a heavy application of mascara!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that it is an [electron microscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_microscope) image. It doesn't use photons, but electrons. So the image has been coloured digitaly.

Comment: +1, but why are the digital colors green?

Comment: "Colored digitally" here means that the color has been artificially added to the image after the fact. Green is simply what this artist happened to choose.

Comment: Also green has maximum response of the human eye.So it helps to give contrast to the detail.